# How to convert stl output to dataframe but keep time series time step?

Tags: r, time-series

I have time series data that where I have used the stl() command to extract seasonality from the data. Now, I want to use the trend data for some other analyses but am having trouble converting the stl output to a dataframe.

I have tried:

```
KK.DF <- as.data.frame(KK14stl$time.series)
```

But that leaves out out the date intervals of the data as this is monthly data for over 40 years in some cases.

I have also tried:

```
KK.DF.V2 <-as.data.frame(as.xts(KK14stl$time.series))
```

But makes a data frame with the monthly dates nested within the column number column and now sure how to extract that from a nameless column. It does not appear when I do

```
names(KK.DF.V2)
```

Any suggestions on how to obtain a data frame with dates and time series data?

Comment: try `KK14stl$trend`. However I often get `NAs` inside this thing so it is difficult to add. In addition I can't help much more, if you do not add some example data.

Answer (score 1):

They are calculated only when you observe the ts object by the `print.ts` method and are not stored in the object. You can plunder `print.ts` for the code that takes into account the various nuances and frequency types.

If you are just wanting a quick fix for monthly data you can use something like:

```
s <- stl(nottem,"per")
s.DF <- as.data.frame(s$time.series)
rownames(s.DF) <- paste(month.abb[cycle(s$time.series)], floor(time(s$time.series)))

head(s.DF)
          seasonal    trend remainder
Jan 1920 -9.347198 49.68067 0.2665254
Feb 1920 -9.855250 49.54552 1.1097288
Mar 1920 -6.853301 49.41037 1.8429318
Apr 1920 -2.763471 49.32862 0.1348488
May 1920  3.501357 49.24688 1.3517676
Jun 1920  8.983303 49.21027 0.3064259
```

Answer (score 0):

The stl output is such:

```
            seasonal    trend     remainder
Jan 1975  0.045860672 7.606192 -1.2870523041
Feb 1975 -0.165838793 7.557013 -1.0261737394
Mar 1975  0.182449236 7.507833  0.8597173305
```

Using as.data.frame yields the following:

```
KK.DF <- as.data.frame(KK14stl$time.series)

       seasonal    trend     remainder
1    0.045860672 7.606192 -1.2870523041
2   -0.165838793 7.557013 -1.0261737394
3    0.182449236 7.507833  0.8597173305
4    0.023504974 7.457380  1.0691145599
5   -0.006006918 7.406927  1.1490794183
6   -0.046599828 7.366488  1.2301122554

names(KK.DF)
"seasonal"  "trend"     "remainder"
```

Using as.xts yields the following:

```
KK.DF.V2 <-as.data.frame(as.xts(KK14stl$time.series))

            seasonal    trend     remainder
Jan 1975  0.045860672 7.606192 -1.2870523041
Feb 1975 -0.165838793 7.557013 -1.0261737394
Mar 1975  0.182449236 7.507833  0.8597173305
Apr 1975  0.023504974 7.457380  1.0691145599
May 1975 -0.006006918 7.406927  1.1490794183
Jun 1975 -0.046599828 7.366488  1.2301122554

names(KK.DF.V2)
"seasonal"  "trend"     "remainder"
```

The KK.DF.V2 data frame has the time time steps but in an unnamed column that I cannot call.